# Java improving Builder pattern on a specific class

Tags: java, builder

currently I have got this class which implements the Builder pattern, for sake of readibility I have chosen to omit some methods, more precisely I only show the build methods of `username`.

```
package dao.constraint;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class AccountConstraint {
    private Constraint<Range<Integer>> accountIdConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> usernameConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> passwordConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> emailConstraint;

    private AccountConstraint(Builder builder) {
        this.accountIdConstraint = builder.accountIdConstraint;
        this.usernameConstraint = builder.usernameConstraint;
        this.passwordConstraint = builder.passwordConstraint;
        this.emailConstraint = builder.emailConstraint;
    }

    public Constraint<Range<Integer>> getAccountIdConstraint() {
        return accountIdConstraint;
    }

    public Constraint<String> getUsernameConstraint() {
        return usernameConstraint;
    }

    public Constraint<String> getPasswordConstraint() {
        return passwordConstraint;
    }

    public Constraint<String> getEmailConstraint() {
        return emailConstraint;
    }

    public Constraint[] getConstraints() {
        return Arrays.asList(this.getAccountIdConstraint(), this.getUsernameConstraint(), this.getPasswordConstraint(), this.getEmailConstraint()).toArray(new Constraint[4]);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Constraint<Range<Integer>> accountIdConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> usernameConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> passwordConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> emailConstraint;

        public Builder() {
            this.accountIdConstraint = null;
            this.usernameConstraint = null;
            this.passwordConstraint = null;
            this.emailConstraint = null;
        }

        public Builder username(final String username) {
            this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(Operation.IS, true, username, "username");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder notUsername(final String username) {
            this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(Operation.IS, false, username, "username");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder usernameLike(final String username) {
            this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(Operation.LIKE, true, username, "username");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder usernameNotLike(final String username) {
            this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(Operation.LIKE, false, username, "username");
            return this;
        }

        public AccountConstraint build() {
            return new AccountConstraint(this);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is very subtle difference between `AccountConstraint.Builder.username(String s)` and `AccountConstraint.Builder.notUsername(String s)`.

I would like to be able to write something like `new AccountConstraint.Builder().not(username(s));`. However as I know this is not valid Java syntax if `username(String s)` is not defined in the calling Java class. I neither wish to repeat the whole `AccountConstraint.Builder()` again to reach the `username(String s)` part. Any solutions?

Second question: Can `AccountConstraint.getConstraints()` be improved or written more simple?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make `not` a method of your builder, setting a flag, which then negates the next constraint.

```
private boolean negate = false;

public Builder not() {
    negate = true;
}

public Builder username(final String username) {
    this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(Operation.IS, !negate, username, "username");
    negate = false;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I find extremely elegant in this situations is to write a utility class with static factory methods like.

```
public static Constraint userName(...) { ... }
```

and to `import static blabla.Utility.username;`

Then you can write almost declarative human-readable queries in java. This is very much as for the hamcrest library for unit testing where you write something like.

```
Assert.assertThat(blabla, is(equalTo(nullValue()));
```

In this case `Not` should implement `Constraint` and just negates the nested (referenced) constraint like this:

```
public static Constraint not(Constraint negated) { return new Not(negated); }
```

this results in code like

```
PreparedStatement ps = new QueryBuilder()
 .select()
 .from(table("accounts")
 .where(not(username(equalTo("blabla")))
 .compile();
```

You can add static factories for boolean combinations:

```
.where(and(
  .not(...),
  .not(or(...))
```

Defining constraints like this (static factory methods as opposed to adding them to the builder) thus makes them easily composable.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

```
   public Constraint[] getConstraints() {
        return Arrays.asList(this.getAccountIdConstraint(), 
            this.getUsernameConstraint(),
            this.getPasswordConstraint(),
            this.getEmailConstraint())
            .toArray(new Constraint[4]);
    }
```

can be re-written to :

```
   public Constraint[] getConstraints() {
        return new Constraint[] {
            this.accountIdConstraint,
            this.usernameConstraint,
            this.passwordConstraint,
            this.emailConstraint
        };
    }
```

But IMO, returning a `List` or `Set` would be better than an array.

Comment: The point is that I got another method accepting a varargs of Constraints, ie. `Constraint... constraints` and I would like to make it accept that. But your suggestion makes it nicer already :)